# How to give non-fixed discount for different fixed prices?

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

we are using Magento version 1.9.2.3 and we want to make one promotion on our site. We have some products in one specific category and our promotion will be: "**Buy product from category 70 and get other products free for the same price.**"

The problem is that the products from category 70 have different prices and we can't fix the discount. The discount has to be exactly as the product's price.

I made Conditions - "**If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE: If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true: Category  is  70**", but can't handle with the Actions

- Apply Percent of Product price discount; Discount Amount: 100;
- Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions:

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE: Category is not  70.

Now the rule is working, but there is no limit of discounting and clients can add products for free by undefined amount.

Can you help me with this kind of promotion? We want when someone buys a product from category 70, he can get other products for the price of this product. Can this be done with Magento's Shopping cart price rules?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you limited the offer to 1 per customer you could do the following for each product at the different price points:

**Conditions:**
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
If total quantity  is equal or greater than  **1**  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions: SKU  is  **PRODUCT A**

**Actions:**
Fixed Amount Discount for Whole Cart
Discount Amount - **Price** of **PRODUCT A**
If ANY  of these conditions are TRUE :
SKU  is one of  **PRODUCT B, PRODUCT C** etc

Beyond this I think it is "impossible" in the standard Magento model.

You need a module that provides a Buy one Get One free feature for different products.  Unfortunately, Magento's in built BOGOF (Buy X Get Y Free) feature will only apply the discount to a single SKU.  I have not used but did consider once the Amasty Special Promotions module and believe this may do what you want - their help desk should be able to answer this.